# Angular 2(4) Material: Animation speed, customizing

Tags: angular, angular-material2

What is the canonical way to set angular-material animation speed?
For example, React material demo page shows exacly what I want.
[React material demo - radiobox](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/radio-button)

And take look please at [angular-material demo - radiobox](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview)

What I want: is to **achieve the same smooth animation experience** from React demos in angular projects.